# AngularJS - interactive svg graphic and back button support

Tags: angularjs

I am implementing an interactive svg graphic embedded in the wonderful angularjs framework which I am just about to discover. My prototype svg graphic is here

[Radial Subgraph](http://justdharma.com/d3/radial-sub-graph/)

Basically on click on nodes the graph display changes and I want to be able to support browser back button to redo clicks. How would be the best way to implement this with AngularJS. I saw the routing facility of AngularJS yet I am not sure if this is the way to go as i dont need different html templates for the different states of the graph display.

Thanks

martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) service to update the URL (it either uses hashbangs or `window.history.pushState`) and then synchronize the url parameters with your application state.

I'd figure out some way to serialize your application's data into a URL (such as query parameters) and then use `$location` to update the URL with each change.

Say, something like:

```
{
    centerNode: "Iris",
    maxDistance: 3
}
```

Which can be URL encoded as:

```
centerNode=Iris&maxDistance=3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. I have no time right now to look into your answer yet that seems to be exactly what i was looking for. Hope to find time later the day to look into it. Thanks again

Comment: so that works perfect for me, thanks a lot http://justdharma.com/d3/radial-sub-graph-history havent implemented yet that a manual change of the url is respected but that is straight forward to do of course - thanks again